# Spring.NET - Lambdas as Dependencies - possible with XML?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, spring.net

I know Spring.NET has support for 'Spring Expressions' - text that is parsed at runtime as code - and that they can be declared in your XML config.

But can you define a lambda expression, and have it parsed and used as a strongly-typed delegate, within your code, say, as a constructor parameter?

Something like this:

```xml
<object name="Page1To2Transition"
    type="XmlVsDslConfig.PageTransition, XmlVsDslConfig">
  <constructor-arg type="string" value="Page1-Page2"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="Page1"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="Page2"/>
  <property name="CanTransition" expression="#CanTransition = {|p| true }"/>
</object>
```

where the PageTransition constructor looks like this:

```
public PageTransition ( 
    String name, 
    Page from, 
    Page to, 
    Func<Page, bool> canTransition )
{/*...*/}
```

Comment: I don't think so, haven't tried but maybe you can ask in the spring.net forums and later on open a jira suggesting that feature?

Comment: Good points - I'm not a particularly big fan of Spring.NET, but wanted to make sure I was giving it a fair assessment (this would be a cool feature though) - might take you up on that.  Thanks

Comment: AFAIK: No. See my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039144/how-to-inject-predicate-and-func-in-spring-net about Func/Predicate injection.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible with using Spring.net Expressions directly. Maybe you can solve your problem of passing a delegate to a constructor / property via xml-config by using the built-in DelegateFactoryObject of Spring.net.

```
  <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.DelegateFactoryObject, Spring.Core"> 
    <property name="DelegateType" value="System.Action"/> 
    <property name="TargetObject" ref="MyTarget" /> 
    <property name="MethodName" value="MyDelegate" /> 
  </object>
```

This will create a delegate of type Action. You can also create delegates of any other type (just specify the type in the property named "DelegateType" (includes the Func delegate you asked for).

Maybe you can use it in combination with expressions to get the result you need.