# Factory configured with Spring returning new Instances for calls at Runtime

Tags: delegates, inversion-of-control, spring.net, factory-pattern

Is there an easy way to use Spring IoC for a factory which returns a new instance at every call **during runtime** (after configuration and context creation)?

I would prefer to avoid a strong dependency to Spring and also **avoid calling GetObject("myFacobj")** everytime... I am looking for something like a method pointer injection instead (as I would do when programming in C instead of C#).

Maybe it is possible to inject a delegate to a factory call using Spring?

Some inspiration might by the post [How to inject Predicate and Func in Spring.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039144/how-to-inject-predicate-and-func-in-spring-net) about injection of delegates (Func<>, ...) but I would prefer an "Spring-Built-In-Solution", if possible.

Comment: It'd be nice if Spring supports injection of Func<TService> factories like Windsor does, but I wasn't able to find any solution how to add support for such behavior in Spring in general..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring.NET supports [method injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection), which could be a good fit here.

I've posted an example in [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026711/possible-getobjectsoftype-replacement/5195658#5195658) on how you might use method injection as an alternative to using `context.GetObject(...)`, so that you don't have to take a dependency the di container.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to method injection. But a problem is the parametrization at runtime, e.g. if you want to set the name of the object (which is set by the constructor). How would you solve that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question in your comment. Shouldn't the method you inject have to account for that? In your case you would register a factory with your container. This factory would have an (abstract or virtual) method `GetNewObjectEveryTime()`. Then you'd configure method injection to provide an implementation for this method. *This* implementation can use runtime-changing parameters to configure new objects.

Comment: If you implement the class that provides the method you want to inject in a separate assembly, you can even choose to let this class depend on the spring.net container, without your other business code taking this dependency.

Comment: Note that you can also specify a [factory method for object creation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-class-static-factory-method), but I assumed this didn't suite you.

Comment: I have tried the Fiona.Apple example in the Spring docs. Thank you for your hints and guidance.